# R-How to generate random sample of a discrete random variables?

Tags: r, binary-data, random

In R,  I want to generate a random sample of a discrete random variable: `X`, where: `P(X=a)=P(X=-a)=1/2`. I have been searching for a function online, but there seems no direct function doing this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are looking to generate samples of a Bernoulli random variable.  A Bernoulli random variable is a special case of a binomial random variable.  Therefore, you can try `rbinom(N,1,p)`.  This will generate `N` samples, with value `1` with probability `p`, value `0` with probability `(1-p)`.  To get values of `a` and `-a` you can use `a*(2*rbinom(N,1,p)-1)`.

Answer (score 10):

1) If you use `sample`, this is sufficient:

`sample(c(-a,a),1)`

e.g.:

```
 a <- 10
 sample(c(-a,a),1)
[1] -10
```

Try another couple:

```
> sample(c(-a,a),1)
[1] -10
> sample(c(-a,a),1)
[1] 10
```

Works.

If you need to sample more than one element, then set `replace=TRUE` ... here we sample 12 times:

```
 sample(c(-a,a),12,replace=TRUE)

 [1]  10  10 -10  10  10  10 -10 -10  10 -10  10 -10
```

2) you can use `runif`; here's a sample of size 9:

```
a <- 1
ifelse(runif(9)<.5,-a,a)

[1] -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1
```

3) you can use `rbinom`; here's a sample of size 4:

```
a <- 6
ifelse(rbinom(4,1,.5),-a,a)

[1] -6  6 -6  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
> n=10
> X=rep(0,n)
> Y=rbinom(n,1,1/2)
> #Since they the probability is 1/2 for both cases, I assigned "a" when Y=1 and "-a" otherwise.
> X[Y==1]="a"
> X[Y==0]="-a"
> X
 [1] "a"  "-a" "a"  "a"  "a"  "-a" "a"  "-a" "-a" "-a"
> Y
 [1] 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
index <- sample(1,c(1,2),replace=T)
if (index == 1) {xx = a} else {xx = -a}
```

Each distribution generating procedure begins with using $\text{uniform}(0,1)$. Since discrete distributions are much easier to generate with $\text{uniform}(0,1)$, people don't wrap up a function for them. However, you can write your own function and just pick them up next time you're going to use them.